# How to get the total number of files in 3 directories?

Tags: shell

How to write a single-line command line invocation that counts the total number of files in the directories /usr/bin, /bin and /usr/doc ?

So far, what I can think of is to use

`cd /usr/bin&&ls -l | wc -l`

but I don't know how to add them together, something like:

`(cd /usr/bin&&ls -l | wc -l) + (cd /bin&&ls -l | wc -l)`

Maybe there is a better way to do it, like get all the stdout of each directory, then pipe to `wc -l`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

how about using find command + wc -l?

```
find /usr/bin /bin /usr/doc -type f |wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ls for multiple directories in conjunction with wc is a little more succinct:

```
ls /usr/bin /bin /usr/doc | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming bash or similarly capable shell, you can use an array:

```
files=(/usr/bin/* /bin/* /usr/doc*)
num=${#files[@]}
```

This technique will correctly handle filenames that contain newlines.

Comment: Your answer seems promising, but I still can't convert string to number`number=1; echo ${#number} + 1 ` I want the output is 2

Comment: If you want to to arithmetic, you have to use bash's arithmetic syntax: `num=3; echo $((num + 1))` -- or `num=3; ((num++)); echo $num`

Comment: `num=3;expr $num + 1` this is only works for me so far, is there any other better way?

Comment: @yozloy, what shell are you using?

Comment: oh-my-zsh, but also can test it in bash

Comment: How are you running your script? with /bin/sh? Both these work in zsh: `((num++))` and `$((num+1))`

Answer (score 0):

As Kent points out, find may be preferred as it will ignore directory entries. Tweak it if you want symbolic links.

A -maxdepth, if your find supports it, is needed unless you want to recurse into any unexpected directories therein. Also throwing away stderr in case a directory is not present for some odd reason.

```
find /usr/bin /bin /usr/doc -maxdepth 1 -type f 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```